# oop inheritance of method vs making object only to call method in class which invoke it

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, single-responsibility-principle

I have problem with judge witch approach is better from design, clean code == good practice.

I load some data from files on start-up of my program and structure of classes looks like this: [image]

To be more specific `IngredientFromXmlReader`, `PizzaReader`, `DrinksFromXmlReader` do all job internally, without any data putted from `DataFromFileLoader` .

The question mark is what with `DataFromFileLoader` class it should inherit from `PizzaReader`, `IngredientFromXmlReader`, `DrinksFromXml` and have method `loadMenuFromFiles` like this:

```
 private void loadMenuFromFiles()
{
    this->loadIngredientsFromXml();
    this->loadPizzasFromXml();
    this->loadDrinksFromXml();    
}
```

This approach:

- looks more clean for me,
- don't create not needed objects,
- and DataFromFileLoader not looks more crowded, then second approach, because methods are implemented in parent classes.

Or just do it how I done it right know, they all have to implement public method `loadXml()`, which is virtual method of `AbstractReaderFromXml`. And then I create object which invoke method.

```
private void loadMenuFromFiles()
    {
        IngredientFromXmlReader ingreRead;
        ingreRead.loadXml();
        PizzaReader pizzaRead;
        pizzaRead.loadXml();
        DrinksFromXmlReader drinksRead;
        drinksRead.loadXml();   
    }
```

Why I choose this:

- it's more stick to single responsibility principle, the responsibilities are more separated, what is advantage,
- i don't give a chance to invoke this method in places, where is not needed, cause I need object to do so,

The third option is to make static this all internally method of these 3 classes, but I don't like it so much. It's seems to me much heavier for application and I try to avoid it. For sure this is the option.

What approach is better ?

The last thing, if this question fit to stackoverflow or maybe it should be put on

> https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: DR; TL; Haven't you heard that [diamond inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) should be avoided in C++.

Comment: @101010 Yeah I heard, but in case when I would like to inherit from these 3 clases, I wouldn't make any virtual methods in class AbstractReaderFromXml, so it would look like in class IngredientFromXmlReader - method loadIngredietnsFromXml instead of this virtual construction loadXml

Comment: @101010 Thx for good argument, that the second option is better then first one. What DR and TL means ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem description in this question looks unclear to me. But I would strongly recommend against diamond inheritance in this case.

Inheritance demonstrates IS-A connection. And `PizzaReader` does not actually look like `FileOpener` to me. `PizzaReader` makes use of `FileOpener` to open files, right? And that means this is a great example of [replacing inheritance with composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: Probably, the better idea would be if I just link the code.  You're right, PizzaReader use methods of FileOpener, thx for help I will refactor my code.

Comment: @MyWay You are welcome. Don't forget that you can mark answers as accepted here if they helped you.